# How to trigger on onpopstate only when there is popup from session history & NOT on pushstate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

While switching from plain HTML5 history API to history.js one significant problem that arises is that onpopstate is triggered even on pushstate. This is problematic for me as I wanted to add callback just to onpopstate as done by HTML5 history API.

Can I some how identify if the statechange was a push or pop operation on history stack
 ?

Comment: Why do you need `History.js`? Would it be simpler to fix your `plain HTML5 history` code?

Comment: Yes seriously I didn't wanted to move but its just because I discovered that I could not support the IE9 & below versions so decided to use a polyfill like history.js. But seems it brings a new set of problems like this with itself.. :(

Comment: Some things can be polyfilled, some things can't.

Comment: so do you suggest not moving to History.js & keep up with plain HTML5 History API ? I too want that but then how do i support IE & all !!? :(

Comment: Just allow normal page navigation to occur.